# Sum and Different and angular momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, commutator

Why is $\overrightarrow{L_{1}}+\overrightarrow{L_{2}}$ an angular momentum operator, but not $\overrightarrow{L_{1}}-\overrightarrow{L_{2}}$?  What does this show about the applicability of the vector model of angular momentum in QM?

I know that any angular momentum operator obeys the relation  $\overrightarrow{L}\times\overrightarrow{L}=i\frac{h}{2\pi}\overrightarrow{L}$, so I was trying to use that to prove the above statement, but I have no idea what to do about the cross terms.

$$(\overrightarrow{L_{1}}+\overrightarrow{L_{2}})\times(\overrightarrow{L_{1}}+\overrightarrow{L_{2}})= [L_{y1},L_{z1}]+[L_{z1},L_{x1}]+[L_{x1},L_{y1}]+[L_{y2},L_{z2}]+[L_{z2},L_{x2}]+[L_{x2},L_{y2}]+[L_{y1},L_{z2}]+[L_{y2},L_{z1}]+[L_{z1},L_{x2}]+[L_{z2},L_{x1}]+[L_{x1},L_{y2}]+[L_{x2},L_{y1}]$$

I know the first 6 terms sum to $i\frac{h}{2\pi}(\overrightarrow{L_{1}}+\overrightarrow{L_{2}})$, which is what I want the final answer to be, but I don't know how to prove the cross terms go to zero, or why they would not for the subtraction case (below).

$$(\overrightarrow{L_{1}}-\overrightarrow{L_{2}})\times(\overrightarrow{L_{1}}-\overrightarrow{L_{2}})= [L_{y1},L_{z1}]+[L_{z1},L_{x1}]+[L_{x1},L_{y1}]+[L_{y2},L_{z2}]+[L_{z2},L_{x2}]+[L_{x2},L_{y2}]-[L_{y1},L_{z2}]-[L_{y2},L_{z1}]-[L_{z1},L_{x2}]-[L_{z2},L_{x1}]-[L_{x1},L_{y2}]-[L_{x2},L_{y1}]$$

Comment: is $X$ meant to be the cross product, $\times$? If so the $\LaTeX$ command is \times

Comment: Yes, it is, and I've edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular momenta should satisfy
$$
[L_i , L_j ] = i \epsilon_{ijk} L_k
$$
If I have two particles with angular momenta $\vec{L}^{(1)}$ and $\vec{L}^{(2)}$. Consider now the quantity $\vec{L} = \vec{L}^{(1)} + \lambda \vec{L}^{(2)}$ and consider its commutator
$$
[ L^{(1)}_i + \lambda L^{(2)}_i , L^{(1)}_j + \lambda L^{(2)}_j ] = i \epsilon_{ijk}  ( L_k^{(1)} + \lambda^2 L_k^{(2)} ) 
$$
where I have used 
$$
[ L^{(1)}_i , L^{(2)}_j ] = 0 
$$
Then, if we require that $\vec{L}$ transforms like an angular momentum, we must have $\lambda^2 = \lambda \implies \lambda = 1$.

EDIT: I have set $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi} = 1$.

Comment: sorry I'm still very confused, Does your first equation require  i=j for or does it hold for any i, j?  Ie do your equations imply that $[L^{1}_{x},L^{2}_{y}]=i\epsilon(L^{1}_{z} +L^{2}_{z})$ taking $\lambda=1$

Comment: It holds for any $i,j=x,y,z$. $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Epsilon symbol that is totally antisymmetric in its indices and $\epsilon_{xyz} = 1$. Finally, the index $k$ that is repeated in the first equation is summed over all possible values that it can take, i.e. it is summed over $x,y,z$.

Comment: My equations do not imply that. As I have clearly mentioned in the last equation, we assume that the two particles are totally non-interacting and hence $[L^1_x , L^2_y] = 0$ and similarly for all other components as well.

Comment: Then I don't understand why the subtraction case isn't also valid since in the way I was solving/proving the question, that would make all the cross terms in the subtraction case go to zero as well.  And what if it can't be assumed that the particles are non-interacting?

Comment: The subtraction case doesn't work because the first six terms you have sum up to $i \frac{h}{2\pi} \left(\vec{L}_1 + \vec{L}_2 \right)$, not $i \frac{h}{2\pi} \left(\vec{L}_1 - \vec{L}_2 \right)$ as it should if $ \vec{L}_1 - \vec{L}_2$ is really an angular momentum.

Comment: wow, I was stupid for not noticing that in the subtraction case, sorry.  Do you have a good reference or explanation  to show that non-interacting particles $[L^{1}_{i},L^{2}_{j}]=0$?

Comment: Actually, I think the non-interacting comment is incorrect. $[L^1_i , L^2_j ] =0 $ even for interacting particles. This is because the two operators act on different Hilbert spaces.